# Vue with dynamic routes and components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

Trying to build a test app to see if Vue is a suitable replacment for our AngularJS app. Trying to learn Vue at the same time.

After the user logs in we fetch some roles for that user.  Base off those roles is how the menu gets built.

User1 { Role1, Role2, Role3}

In theory

User2 {Role1, Role3}

So Role1 would have a path of /start/page1 and page1 (component) and two child components. 
Same with Role2 path of /start/page2 and page2 would have components on it.

I don't really want to build the routes until I know which roles the user has.

I'm using quasar-framework.org and using the menu slide out.  Trying to create a menu on the fly. Seems like I need the components to already be imported?

I'm able to build the menu by looping through the roles and setting up a list of menus.

Trying to build the routes on the fly using  this.$router.addRoutes(newRoute);
To do that I need the component to already be imported.

The Quasar way is load the components on the fly I guess.

In router.js

```
function loadPage (component) {
  return () => import(`../../pages/${component}.vue`)
}
```

I can't seem to use that function in a method section.

Is this possible in Vue?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [vue-router lazy loading documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) and [Quasar lazy loading documentation](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-lazy-loading---code-splitting.html)

You can't do it in a method, but if the user permission don't match the route permissions the component is never loaded, which is basically what you want.

Example

```
  const routes = [
    {
      path: '/some-page-protected',
      component: () => import('pages/SomePage'),
      meta: {role: 'admin'}
    }
  ]
```

Or

```
  const SomePage = () => ('pages/SomePage')
  const routes = [
    {
      path: '/some-page-protected',
      component: SomePage,
      meta: {role: 'admin'}
    }
  ]
```